# SelectGroupByInto is not grouping!

Tags: c#, .net, database, datatable, dataset

I'm trying to use [this implementation of a DataSetHelper](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326145) to group a DataSet by a column.

What I'm doing is:

```
DataSet ds_tmp = new DataSet();
DataTable dt_tmp;
ds_tmp.Tables.Add(data_table_UserTime);
dsHelper = new DataSetHelper(ref ds_tmp);
dt_tmp = dsHelper.SelectGroupByInto("UniqueUsers", ds_tmp.Tables[0], "User, sum(Time) TotalTime", "Time>0", "User");
```

**data_table_UserTime** is something like this:

> **User**------**Time**
>
> John------0.6
>
> Mark------1.2
>
> Paul------7.1
>
> John------52.6
>
> John------0.8
>
> Paul------50.3

At the end, **dt_tmp** should have this:

> **User**------**Time**
>
> John------54.0
>
> Mark------1.2
>
> Paul------57.4

But what I get is this:

> **User**------**Time**
>
> John------0.6
>
> John------52.6
>
> John------0.8
>
> Mark------1.2
>
> Paul------7.1
>
> Paul------50.3

So it seems it is not doing the sum(Time).

What can be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I never thought it would be a bug in the DataSetHelper class. It seems it has some problems with numeric values.

The function ColumnEqual should be changed to:

```
private bool ColumnEqual(object a, object b)
{
    /*
     * Compares two values to see if they are equal. Also compares DBNULL.Value.
     *
     * Note: If your DataTable contains object fields, you must extend this
     * function to handle them in a meaningful way if you intend to group on them.
    */
    if ((a is DBNull) && (b is DBNull))
        return true;    //both are null
    if ((a is DBNull) || (b is DBNull))
        return false;    //only one is null
    return (a.ToString() == b.ToString());    //value type standard comparison
}
```

The difference is in a.ToString() == b.ToString(), that originaly was a==b.

Thanks anyway!